# How to switch between fragments without having to recreate each one?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I currently have 5 fragments that I can switch between but each time I switch, the fragment that becomes active, recreates itself. I want to know how I can make it so that if a fragment is no longer displaying, it's state is still saved in the background so when I come back to this fragment, it is still how it was left. This is the current code that I have..

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/zero"
    android:layout_weight="12"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/theNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/zero"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/oneButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1A1A1A"
        android:src="@mipmap/one"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/twoButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1A1A1A"
        android:src="@mipmap/two"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/threeButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1A1A1A"
        android:src="@mipmap/three"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fourButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1A1A1A"
        android:src="@mipmap/four"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fiveButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/zero"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1A1A1A"
        android:src="@mipmap/five"
        android:onClick="onSelectFragment" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_one.xml, fragment_two.xml, fragment_three.xml, fragment_four.xml, fragment_five.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentOne.java, FragmentTwo.java, FragmentThree.java, FragmentFour.java, FragmentFive.java (Each with their respective layout files):

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton one;
    private ImageButton two;
    private ImageButton three;
    private ImageButton four;
    private ImageButton five;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        FragmentOne oneFragment = new FragmentOne();

        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, oneFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
        two = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.twoButton);
        three = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.threeButton);
        four = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fourButton);
        five = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fiveButton);
    }

    public void onSelectFragment(View view) {
        Fragment newFragment;

        if (view == findViewById(R.id.oneButton)) {
            newFragment = new FragmentOne();
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.twoButton)) {
            newFragment = new FragmentTwo();
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.threeButton)) {
            newFragment = new FragmentThree();
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.fourButton)) {
            newFragment = new FragmentFour();
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.fiveButton)) {
            newFragment = new FragmentFive();
        } else {
            newFragment = new FragmentOne();
        }

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Create fields in your activity for each fragment. Lazy-initialize them if you want, so instances are only created when needed. But the key is for you to hold onto those fragment instances. Right now, you are creating brand new ones on every `onSelectFragment()` call.

Answer (score 0):

you could use FragmentPagerAdapter to manage your fragments, which is a handful way to show some static fragments.
  You can get more informations here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use attach and detach method of FragmentTransaction, using a tag to identify the fragment.

Here an example:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    selectFragment( FragmentOne.class.getName() );

    one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
    two = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.twoButton);
    three = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.threeButton);
    four = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fourButton);
    five = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fiveButton);
}

public void onSelectFragment(View view) {

    String className;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.oneButton)) {
        className = FragmentOne.class.getName();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.twoButton)) {
        className = FragmentTwo.class.getName();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.threeButton)) {
        className = FragmentThree.class.getName();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.fourButton)) {
        className = FragmentFour.class.getName();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.fiveButton)) {
        className = FragmentFive.class.getName();
    } else {
        className = FragmentOne.class.getName();
    }

    selectFragment( className );
}

private void selectFragment( String fragClassName )
{
    // Init transaction
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    // Get current Fragment
    Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( mCurrFragment );

    // If found and different from current required detach it
    if( currentFragment != null )
        fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);

    // Attach (create if first time) new Fragment
    Fragment newFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragClassName);
    if (newFragment != null)
    {
        fragmentTransaction.attach(newFragment);
    }
    else
    {
        newFragment = Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, newFragmentClass);
        newFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        fragmentTransaction.add( R.id.fragment_placeholder, newFragment, newFragmentClass );
    }

    // Commit
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    mCurrFragment = fragClassName;
}
```

Be aware of configuration changes.

FragmentManager keeps fragment over activity recreation but it calls again all lifecycle methods.
If you set setRetainInstance to true, it is called all methods except onCreate/onDestroy, so you can create there all "heavy" stuff that you do not want to loose.

Comment: If you use `findFragmentById` with `R.id.fragment_placeholder` to find the current fragment instead, you can get rid of the `mCurrFragment` variable altogether.

Comment: @cascal, mCurrFragment is also used by me (not in the pasted code), to check if we are not selecting the current fragment. To avoid to unusefully detach and attach it.